# Dynamic memory C, realloc exception

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to write code using dynamic memory allocation, and facing the problem that when `realloc()` is called in `genPointLinkArray()`, the program throws an exception: `ConsoleApplication1.exe has triggered a breakpoint`.

I am using Visual Studio 15 and running the program in Debug mode.

```
struct graphPoint
{
    point p;
    int value;
};
struct graphLink
{
    point start;
    graphPoint end;
};
graphLink* genPointLink(char map[10][10], point start, graphPoint primaryPoint[22], int *linksNum)
{
    graphLink *lin = (graphLink*)0;
    (*linksNum) = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
    {
        if (!ifWay(map, start, primaryPoint[i].p))
        {
            (*linksNum)++;
            if(*linksNum == 1)
                lin = (graphLink*)malloc(sizeof(graphLink));
            else
            {
                lin = (graphLink*)realloc(lin, (*linksNum) * sizeof(graphLink));
            }
            (lin + (*linksNum - 1))->start = start;
            (lin + (*linksNum - 1))->end = primaryPoint[i];
        }
    }
    return lin;

}

graphLink* genPointLinkArray(char map[10][10], graphPoint primaryPoint[22],  int *linksNum)
{
    graphLink *links = (graphLink*)0, *l;
    int currentNum = 0;
    *linksNum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
    {
        l = genPointLink(map, primaryPoint[i].p, primaryPoint, &currentNum);
        if(currentNum != 0)
            if (*linksNum == 0)
                links = (graphLink*)calloc(currentNum, sizeof(graphLink));
            else
                links = (graphLink*)realloc(links, ((currentNum + *linksNum) * sizeof(graphLink)));
        *linksNum = *linksNum + currentNum;
        for (int i = 0; i < currentNum; i++)
        {
            links[*linksNum - 1 + i].end = l[i].end;
            links[*linksNum - 1 + i].start = l[i].start;
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < *linksNum; i++)
    {
        printf("(%d ; %d) -> (%d ; %d) : %d\n", links[i].start.x, links[i].start.y, links[i].end.p.x, links[i].end.p.y, links[i].end.value);
    }

    return links;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have a breakpoint set in your editor? Have you tried running in non-debug mode to see if the same issue arises?

Comment: Side note: take note that `malloc` & co can fail. You **have to** check their return values.

Comment: when i run in non-debug mode, programm don't send any outputs

Comment: `graphPoint end;` --> `struct graphPoint end;`

Comment: `sizeof(graphLink)` --> `sizeof(struct graphLink)`

Comment: BTW the posted code cannot compile. You forgot all `struct` keyword on all types...

Comment: What is displayed in the Output window (Menu Debug->Windows->Output) ?

Comment: @J.Doe and a [MCVE] could help too.

Comment: The logic of the memory allocations is not readily obvious, because you are not using the loop controls to decide whether to use `realloc` or not. May I suggest that having set `lin = NULL` (as you do, and `links = NULL`) you then use only `realloc` in the loop? Also, I note you use `calloc` and `realloc` but `realloc` does not clear the new memory allocation. Will that be a problem, seeing as `calloc` is usually called for a reason in preference to `malloc`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the following part of code

```
    *linksNum = *linksNum + currentNum;
    for (int i = 0; i < currentNum; i++)
    {
        links[*linksNum - 1 + i].end = l[i].end;
        links[*linksNum - 1 + i].start = l[i].start;
    }
```

You update the `*linksNum` before the loop, so inside the loop you are addressing the `links` "array" out of bound: **Undefined Behavior.**